# Logarithm of the maximum equals maximum of logarithm

Tags: optimization, logarithms

Does anybody know how to prove that the maximum of the logarithm of a given function equals the logarithm of the maximum of the function? That is, if $f$ is a function of $x$, how to prove that

$$\log(\max(f(x)))=\max(\log(f(x)))$$

It seems to be a obvious equality, and I have checked it numerically, but is there a simple way to prove it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that the logarithm is an increasing function. Let $y$ be a point such that $f(y) = \max(f(x))$. Then for any $x\neq y$ we have $f(x) \le f(y)$ and thus
$$
\log(f(x)) \le \log(f(y)) = \log(\max(f(x))).
$$
Can you finish the proof?

Comment: In that way I have that $\max(\log(f))\leq \log\max(f)$. Is the other inequality obtained in a similar way?

Comment: Well, evaluating the inequality $\log(f(x))\leq \log(\max(f(x)))$ in $y$ I have finished, haven't I?

Comment: In the above comment there is a mistake, I evaluate in $\log(f(x))\leq \max(\log(f(x)))$

Comment: @JN_2605 Indeed your first comment is correct. For the reverse implication by the definition of the max we must have $\max(\log(f(x))) \ge \log(f(y)) = \log(\max(f(x)))$.